# SQL Server Date Column Inconsistent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column date with string(nvarchar) format. and I have inconsistent column like this

[image: Inconcsistent Date Column]

I have more example like this

```
2021-7-01
2021-8-01
```

first I have try with CASE WHEN like this

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN DATE_IN LIKE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, date_in, 102)
                    WHEN date_in LIKE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, date_in) END AS DATE_IN, EMP_NAME,DATE_IN
FROM staging.irisEtcSingleFile
```

but, the output is NULL ..
I want the output is like this

```
2021-01-01
2021-07-01
2021-08-01
```

I really appreciate to get the answer .. Thanks before

Comment: Why are you storing dates as text? That's a cardinal sin right there.

Comment: no, its table staging .. the source is txt file from blob storage ...

Comment: Why can't your parse dates and use the correct column type when you import the data in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this query using

> replicate

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN test_col LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]',4) + '-[0-9]-' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',2)
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, test_col, 102)
                    WHEN test_col LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]',4) + '-' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',2) + '-' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',2)
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, test_col) END AS test_col
FROM test
```

Comment: select 
case when LEN(DATE_IN) < 10 then LEFT(DATE_IN,LEN(DATE_IN)-5 +'0'+RIGHT(date_in,5)) end as date_in_new
,date_in, EMP_NAME from staging.irisEtcSingleFile

I have query too .. but error Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '-1-01' to data type int.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippets, produces a good response:

```
create table #t (txt varchar(100))
delete from #t
go

insert into #t select '2021-7-01'
insert into #t select '2021-8-01'
insert into #t select '2021-01-01'
insert into #t select '2021-07-01'
insert into #t select '2021-2-02'
insert into #t select '2021-08-01'

go

select 
    txt
from 
    #t
where
    txt not like '%[^0-9-]%' and
    len(replace(txt, '-', '')) = len(txt)-2 and
    txt like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
```

Output:

```
2021-01-01
2021-07-01
2021-08-01
```